# Looking to enter NZ on one passport and leave on another

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, new-zealand

Looking to enter NZ as an Australian and leave on another unused foreign passport. Can it be done without issue or will NZ require the Oz passport on leaving?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?
See this question - http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel - even if you want to enter the next country with your other passport, you don't have to use it to leave NZ.

Comment: I want to do it because I want to do it. End of discussion.

Comment: Knowing why might help others to suggest a better solution, or show us how it is different (if it is) to the current marked duplicate.

Comment: Given that NZ has an exit check, they're almost certainly going to want to match your exit to an entry record, so it appears that the answer to your question is that it can't be done and they will require the Australian passport.  If you try it, please post an answer and report what actually happens.

Answer (score 2):

Do citizens of the other "foreign" country require visas to visit New Zealand?  That could raise questions if so.  And even if not, the Immigration officer might want to know why you are doing it that way.

There is no advantage to exiting with a different passport, as New Zealand does not stamp passports upon exit.  So you won't get a stamp in the other passport to show you have been in NZ.

If it is an issue of entry into the destination country and airlines letting you on board, checking in is totally separate from Immigration, so you can show the foreign passport when checking in, then clear Immigration with the same passport you entered with.

Comment: More to the point, the Immigration officer will *definitely* want to know how you got to NZ if they can't find any entry records for your other passport.

Comment: Do you have actual experience of this?

Comment: Experience of what?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a reason that you would need to actually do this. When you leave New Zealand, you must go through exit passport control. This is an immigration checkpoint where an officer inspects your passport to record your exit and ensure that you are permitted to leave (not have any outstanding warrants for your arrest, for example).

At the point you go through exit passport control, simply hand the officer the same passport (in your case, Australian) that you used to enter the country. They'll record your exit and hand it back straight away. This does not need to be the same passport you told your airline about (for example, if you are travelling to the US and needed to get an ESTA). Exit passport control is not interested in whether you have permission to enter the *next* country on your itinerary, that's the airline's concern.

You may have more problems in the future if you try to leave NZ on a passport other than the one you entered with.

Comment: None of the replies actually answers my question. I have a valid reason for my travel plan.

Comment: @bloogs If you _had_ a valid reason, you could share it _and already would have_ shared it.